# Unity Path Finding for Multiple Vehicles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm currently making a game in Unity where I need to be able to generate routes for vehicles. The only consraints I really have are:

- Each building the city must have be visited once by a vehicle
- The vehicles are all dispatched from the same spot
- The workload must be distributed (ie, each vehicle must visit some buildings, doesn't have to be perfectly equal)

I'm aware that this problem is essentially VRP which is NP-hard, however I'm not too worried about finding an optimal solution as the player will have control over manual vs automatic route generation for each vehicle. Was just wondering if anyone else had come up against this issue, specifically in Unity, and how it might be approached. I'm aware that I need to use a data structure for manual routing which can also be used for route generation.

Comment: Can buildings be visited more than once?

Comment: @KitM yes, they can

Answer (score -1):

Implement this:

1. Create array for each vehicle
2. Create array for each building
3. Choose random building
4. Choose random vehicle
5. Add building to vehicle array
6. Remove building from building array

You now have lists of buildings for each vehicle. If the vehicles need to visit each in order, sort them by distance to the start point.